# Blazor WebAssembly And Razor Class Library

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a Blazor Web Assembly Project, and I need to add Razor Class Library and reference it in my project file, I'm facing the [following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z49xM.png)

```
Error   NETSDK1082  There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.    Demo    C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets   430
```

This is my code:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>AngryMonkey.Cloud.Components.Demo</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>AngryMonkey.Cloud.Components.Demo</RootNamespace>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Configurations>Debug;Release;Release_Server</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <WarningLevel>1</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="src\js\site.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Components\Components.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\css\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompile Include="src\js\site.ts" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I tried replacing `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">` by `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">` and I got the following error:

blazor.webassembly.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Components.csproject file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
        <AssemblyName>AngryMonkey.Cloud.Components</AssemblyName>
        <RootNamespace>AngryMonkey.Cloud.Components</RootNamespace>
        <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
        <Product>Cloud Components</Product>
        <Authors>Angry Monkey</Authors>
        <Company>Angry Monkey</Company>
        <Description />
        <PackageLicenseExpression></PackageLicenseExpression>
        <PackageProjectUrl>https://www.angrymonkeycloud.com/</PackageProjectUrl>

        <AssemblyVersion>$(PackageVersion)</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>$(PackageVersion)</FileVersion>
        <Version>2.0.3</Version>
        <PackageIcon>AngryMonkeyCloudLogo-64x64.png</PackageIcon>
        <PackageOutputPath>..\NugetPackage\</PackageOutputPath>

        <Configurations>Debug;Release;Release_Server</Configurations>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="AngryMonkeyCloudLogo-64x64.png">
            <Pack>True</Pack>
            <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Remove="Icons\**" />
        <Content Remove="Icons\**" />
        <EmbeddedResource Remove="Icons\**" />
        <None Remove="Icons\**" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove=".mateconfig.json" />
        <Content Remove="tsconfig.json" />
        <Content Remove="wwwroot\cloud.css" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Remove="CloudWeb\css\cloud.css" />
        <None Remove="ProgressBar\progressbar.min.js" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <SupportedPlatform Include="browser" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="GridView\" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include=".mateconfig.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Include="tsconfig.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Include="wwwroot\cloud.css" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="CloudWeb\css\cloud.css" Pack="true">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>

        <EmbeddedResource Include="CloudWeb\css\cloud.min.css" Pack="true">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>

        <EmbeddedResource Include="CloudWeb\js\cloud.js" Pack="true">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>

        <EmbeddedResource Include="CloudWeb\js\cloud.min.js" Pack="true">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>

        <EmbeddedResource Include="General\css\variables.less" Pack="true">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>

        <EmbeddedResource Include="General\css\common.less" Pack="true">
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </EmbeddedResource>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

dotnet --info

```
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.401
 Commit:    0906eae6f8

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19044
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.401\

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.9
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       163a63591c

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.29 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Comment: What's the target framework for your referenced project `..\Components\Components.csproj`?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29700

Comment: I added my dotnet --info and components.csproject information

Comment: I created a new wasm project with a new library, it seems to work fine and shows my referenced component but in my case it doesnt. this is the link to the github repository https://github.com/angrymonkeycloud/CloudComponents